# javascript to decide on call to stopPropagation after async computation

Tags: javascript, async-await

There is a container-component structure of HTML elements. Container element has a `click` handler attached to it. Actions of this handler are good enough for most of the content. But some of the components have their own `click` handlers and more specific conditional behavior. Under some conditions the event should not propagate outside the component, that is to say container is prevented from reacting on such `click` events.

It is easy to stop an event from bubbling synchronously.

Is it possible to defer the decision until some long async computation completed?

```
component.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (e)=>{
        // this is OK, but conditions are not known yet
        if(flag) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        setTimeout(
           ()=>compute(), 
           1500,
        );
    },
)
```

Is it possible to postpone the decision whether to stop the event propagation on after computation is done.

```
(e)=>{
    setTimeout(
       ()=>{ 
           flag = compute(), 
           if(flag) {
               // this will not work as expected
               e.stopPropagation();
            }
       },
       1500,
    );
}
```

What is recommended solution to use HTMLElement::click() on component's parent element or event.target.parentElement?

```
(e)=>{
    e.stopPropagation();        
    setTimeout( 
       ()=>{
           const flag = compute();
           if(!flag){
               component.parentElement.click();
               // e.target.parentElement.click();
           }
       }, 
       1500,
    );
}
```

Is there a better way of doing so?

Comment: No, it's not possible to call `e.stopPropagation()` asynchronously. The async function won't run until after the propagation happens, it can't go back in time to stop it.

Comment: The general solution is to always call `e.stopPropagation()`, and pass a callback that performs the desired action to the async code.